# resolving composer conflict - unclear on dependency 'rules'

Tags: php, composer-php, guzzle

I have a version of laravel that I am trying to add a third-party non-laravel webservice api wrapper into. the wrapper has a requirement for guzzle >= 6 and the version of laravel has a requirement for guzzle ^7

Looking at the api, it doesn't use anything complex in guzzle so I'm pretty sure it's usage of it will be compatible with v7. Reading the composer docs, I see where it says the use of the caret restricts it to => 7 but < 8, but I don't understand why the >= 6 on the second package is causing a conflict (it's not using the caret and is saying it can use anything greater than 6)

How do I resolve this conflict so I can use this API within my website code?

updated:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires jacob-hyde/printify ^1.0 -> satisfiable by jacob-hyde/printify[v1.0].
    - jacob-hyde/printify v1.0 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ^6.3 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.3.0, ..., 6.5.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^7.0.1).

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

Comment: Please [edit] and provide a minimum example `composer.json` with ony the two requires that cause you the issue. then the minimum command to invoke (e.g. composer update) and the output (shortened) to the error message you are asking about.

Comment: "is causing a conflict" - what does that mean? Do you see any specific error message?

Comment: updated with composer output

Comment: "jacob-hyde/printify v1.0 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ^6.3 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.3.0, ..., 6.5.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^7.0.1)." sounds pretty obvious to me. That library explicitly requires Guzzle v6, and your own application requires Guzzle v7

Comment: Seriously?!? Did you read the question? How is version 7 NOT greater than 6??!?!  The composer.json in the jacob-hyde package is >= 6 -- dunno why composer is deciding to show it as ^6 here. https://github.com/jacob-hyde/Printify-PHP-SDK/blob/master/composer.json

Comment: I have no clue why you think that the requirement for v1.0 should be anything else than `^6.3`. The requirement you link to is the one from the master branch, but that's not the one you have required in your application

Comment: I included the link to the composer in the other package. it does not say ^6.3, it says >=6.3

Comment: "require": {
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": ">=6.3"
    },

Comment: there is only one branch in that other package: https://github.com/jacob-hyde/Printify-PHP-SDK/branches

Comment: ok, I see it now - apparently his one on packagist has a different composer.json than the one on github

Comment: There might be only one branch, but there's also an additional tag at https://github.com/jacob-hyde/Printify-PHP-SDK/blob/v1.0/composer.json

Comment: Hmm, so if I follow this right, a `compose require jacob-hyde/printify:dev-master` instead of the initial `compose require jacob-hyde/printify:^1.0` should have done it, as the master banch has the fix. And in parallel kindly asking the maintainer to tag a new release including the fixes since v1.0.

Answer (score -1):

OK, as shown in the comments - the one that was published on packagist had a different composer.json than the one on github. For the time being, I'm just adding a repositories entry in the composer.json rather than creating/refactoring/testing a fork while building my own api interface. *ugh*

Comment: "the one that was published on packagist had a different composer.json than the one on github." - no, that's not the case. You've read the `composer.json` for the master branch, but you've installed a different version of that package

Comment: and the different version is the one on packagist which had a different composer.json - that is the case. Why is this even something worth arguing? Jeesh - It's solved. move along

Comment: Can you share more details? Comparing the dependencies from https://packagist.org/packages/jacob-hyde/printify with those in the Github repository, I cannot see a difference